# SET and SELECT within a single query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm wondering if it's possible to SET and SELECT within a single query. Something like this:

```
SET LOCAL search_path TO "1"; SET LOCAL ROLE "user"; SELECT * from posts;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
with some_set as (
  select set_config('search_path', '"1"', true)
)
select * from posts;
```

or just `SELECT` with `set_config()` calls w/o CTE, but this in general will not help you because:

- there is no guarantee that you'll get desired order of execution of you query's parts (remember, that SQL is a declarative language, see also https://www.google.com/search?q=postgresql+cte+order+not+guaranteed&oq=postgresql+cte+order+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59l2j69i64.6362j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8, and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86263/managing-cte-execution-order-under-uncertainty)
- AFAIK there is no way to switch DB role with `SELECT`.

Comment: Thanks @Nick! Just to be clear, does WITH ensure that it will execute before `select * from posts`? Or not even that?

Comment: no, it does not: "when using data-modifying statements in WITH, the order in which the specified updates actually happen is unpredictable." https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html – in my experiments, main `SELECT` was executed *before* `select set_config`, that's why I wrote that it will not help you.

Comment: Looks like `select set_config('timezone', tzone, true), to_char(tstamp, mask)` works as expected.